# Using and in active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is is allowed to use AND condition in active record? FOr example

```
Model.where(a>b AND c>d).all
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AND is the default scope for joining conditions. OR is trickier.

`Model.where('a > b and c > d')` or `Model.where('a > b').where('c > d')`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Model.where("a > ? AND c > ?", @my_b_variable, params[:d])

... works.

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions

Comment: Oh.  I like sevenseacat's answer better.